# What are these components in this schematic?

Tags: transistors, components, schematics

I have a schematic of my mobile phone. when i saw in the schematic, i saw two odd component. look:

[image: schematic]

- For number one: What are these both components? What's the usage of
  these?
- For number two: Is it a transistor? What's the difference between this
  component and a transistor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 NTHS5441 Power MOSFET  −20 V, −5.3 A, P−Channel ChipFET

2 UNRF2A1001 NPN junction transistor IC - transistor + internal resistors (appears to be obsolete device from  Panasonic)

Comment: The part numbers "NTHS5441T1G" and "UNRF2A1001ER" shown on the schematic can be searched in Google and the manufacturer's data sheets show up. This is a handy technique any time you have an unknown component with part numbers on it.

Comment: How do you know these components?

Answer (score 4):

1 is a MOSFET

2 is a BJT (Bipolar Junction Transistor), what's commonly just named "transistor", but with integrated resistors. Usually you'll have to add these resistors externally.